# How to created a hole through chipboard / melamine to look behind a cupboard

Tags: plumbing, cabinets, smell, melamine

There is a cupboard in a bathroom that appears to have some strange smell coming from behind the wall.

We've checked the sink to see if its leaking and there is no sign of that, have cleaned through the drainage pipes underneath and are now left to look behind the wall.

How is the best way to cut though the wall so that I minimise damanage and are able to repair the area behind the cabinet afterwards?

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: It's hard to give much advice without more info about the situation.

Comment: What is on the other side of the wall - outside of house? another room? Are the walls drywall or something else? Have you ruled out other plumbing (toilet, tub/shower drain)?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a question for an electrician. ;-)

Get a single-gang or two-gang old work low voltage bracket. (photos: homedepot.com)

[image: 1-gang bracket]
[image: 2-gang bracket]

Cut a hole in the back of the cabinet to accommodate the low voltage bracket. Use a jig saw, hand saw, oscillating multi-tool, reciprocating saw.. whatever you have available with a suitable blade. Before cutting, make some effort to estimate the location of the wall studs and then position your hole so it won't overlap a wall stud.

When you've finished having a look inside the wall, install the bracket and a blank cover plate. Finished! (photo: lowes.com)

[image: cover plate]